# vertically align multiple lines of text with image (responsive, div dynamic), image size getting scaled to 4times

Tags: html, css, wordpress, vertical-alignment

Its been so frustrating with CSS, I have really hard time figuring how to do this.

Let me explain what exactly I am trying to achieve. I am using wordpress and have a div in which I am trying to vertically align both multiple lines of text and image, so that text becomes centered to image. Image is responsive, as well as div size is dynamic. I have tried with fixed width and height for image and text, using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

The issue is the image is getting scaled to 4times its uploaded size

HTML

```
<div class="image">
     <img class="size-full wp-image-12291 alignleft"src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/terminal1.png" />
     <p>I want to get it centered</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    display:table;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.image:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    bottom: -25px;
}
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The problem is it is scaling the image to 4 times its uploaded size.

I have used display-table with fixed height and width for image and text block, it worked well. I am trying to work it out for responsive images.

Is there a reason, that this is happening because of wordpress, because, when you upload image to wordpress, it has an option for image size class as medium and large. The large image size is being taken as the class, if you notice in the HTML. Is this happening as I am specifying 100%.

Comment: Seems to work fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mfLq/ on Chrome/Win7 What is the CSS for `.size-full` and `.wp-image-12291`?

Comment: I think there must be a problem with wordpress

Comment: yeah, you are right, its working in the fiddle, but weird, I am not able to get it right with wordpress

Comment: I don't think it is a "problem" with Wordpress, I'm assuming it is behaving as expected for the settings that it has been given. Use developer tools to see what `.size-full` and `.wp-image-12291` are doing and you should be able to override it.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, what you tried with display: table-cell is exactly what you need. Just don't use it on your image but on an surrounding element instead. So your image stays the same size. right now you use width: 100%, that scales your image.

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <img class="size-full wp-image-12291 alignleft"src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </div>
    <p class="cell">I want to get it centered</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GHVKM/1/